# Hide navigation bar and toolbar on touch

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

Does anyone have any info or code on how to can hide a navigation bar and toolbar when the user touches the iphone screen.

Basically I have an image gallery and I want to see the images in the whole of the iphone screen.

also im trying to implement a button so the user can download the image i had no luck on my search on google.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES]
2. as I remember, there is smth like setHidden: method for any view. toolbar is a view.
3. handling touches. see touchesBegan:withEvents: in UIResponder.
4. you cannot download image? how do you try to do it? what the problem is?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, i think i missed that method but i will use it thanks. Also do you know if i need to implement it on a touches delegate or make the navigation buttons?
I have a scroll view with images downloaded from the internet i would like the user to download the image on to there iPhone Photo library with a button on the navigation bar